# How do I save HTML files as non-formatted text, not code, using a programming language?

Tags: html, batch-file, interpreter

I know this question is sort of general, but I'm making an extension to my Windows 10 Command Prompt allowing you to view HTML as plain text within the program. I don't know if it would be considered lazy not to build an interpreter for something like this, but it just seems like too much work for something only I will be using. Making  an interpreter for a markup language I know little about seems unnecessary and making it in Batch would be even harder.

I know how to read from files and store them as a variable, but my question would be how to store raw HTML as plain text without any formatting. For instance,

```
<p>Here's some text.</p>
```

Would become:

```
Here's some text.
```

I'd like an interpreter to convert the HTML into plain text. It doesn't need to be written in Batch, but it's fine if it is. I'd prefer it be written into a more developed language, though, such as Python, which I've seen used to interpret programming languages before. It doesn't need to be written by you, so a referral would be fine.

Sorry if I took my time explaining. Even a partial solution would be fine. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please show some code to demonstrate that you've attempted to solve the problem on your own.  Questions resembling, "Here are my requirements.  Now write it for me or find me a tool" typically aren't well-received around here.

But partly to stem off further half answers and partly because I relished the challenge, here's a solution written as a hybrid Batch + JScript script that will write the `innerText` of your HTML to the console.  Save it with a .bat extension.  If you want the output to go to a file instead then `batscript.bat htmlfile > outfile.txt` at the cmd line.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%outfile%" < "%~1"
goto :EOF

:usage
2>&1 echo Usage: %~nx0 htmlfile
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript

var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.write(WSH.StdIn.ReadAll());

WSH.Echo(htmlfile.documentElement.innerText);
htmlfile.close();
```

IE9 compatibility mode is invoked to recognize more HTML element types than without, while still allowing Vista compatibility.  You can change `IE=9` to 10, 11, or Edge if needed.

---

If you'd prefer a non-hybrid script, you can also construct the `htmlfile` COM object using PowerShell.  It's slower to execute, but it is simpler code (odd .NET-ish method names notwithstanding).  Examples:

**.bat script:**

```js
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage

set "htmlfile=%~f1"

set "psCommand="^
    $h=new-object -COM htmlfile;^
    $h.IHTMLDocument2_write('^<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" /^>');^
    $h.IHTMLDocument2_write(${%htmlfile%});^
    $h.documentElement.innerText""

powershell -noprofile -noninteractive %psCommand%

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 htmlfile
goto :EOF
```

**.ps1 script:**

```perl
param( $htmlfile = $false )

if (-not (test-path $htmlfile)) {
    [console]::Error.WriteLine("Usage: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name) htmlfile")
    exit
}

$html = gc $htmlfile | out-string
$hObj = new-object -COM htmlfile
$hObj.IHTMLDocument2_write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />')
$hObj.IHTMLDocument2_write($html)
$hObj.documentElement.innerText
$hObj.Close()
```

(Example usage of the .ps1 solution: `powershell .\scriptname.ps1 htmlfile.html`)

---

And because I'm doing this for the personal challenge, here's a batch + HTA hybrid variation that pastes the `innerText` unsaved into a new Notepad window, because I can.

```js
<!-- : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

if "%~1"=="" goto usage
if not exist "%~1" goto usage

mshta "%~f0" < "%~1"
goto :EOF

:usage
2>&1 echo Usage: %~nx0 htmlfile
goto :EOF

end Batch / begin HTA -->

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />
<div id="out"></div>

<script>
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    osh = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'),
    notepad = osh.Exec('notepad');

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = fso.GetStandardStream(0).ReadAll();
clipboardData.setData('text', document.getElementById('out').innerText);

var waitActive = setInterval(function() {
    if (osh.AppActivate(notepad.ProcessID)) {
        clearInterval(waitActive);
        close(osh.SendKeys('^v'));
    }
}, 25);

</script>
```

I used HTA to circumvent browser security preventing write access to the clipboard (as happens with the `htmlfile` COM object), and because HTA is lighter weight and less likely to end up as an invisible running process than an `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and can also be run from command line.

```
$url = 'http://www.somedoma.in/some_file.htm';
$website =  file_get_contents($url);
echo strip_tags($website);
```

Then you can use [php.exe](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.Visible = 0
ie.Silent = 1 
ie.Navigate2 "file://" & FilterPath & "Filter.html"

Do 
    wscript.sleep 50            
Loop Until ie.document.readystate = "complete"

ie.document.body.innerhtml = Inp.readall
Outp.write ie.document.body.innertext

'ie.quit
```

`InP.ReadAll` is the html text in a textstream object, `OutP` contains plain text in another textstream object.

Navigate to a local file to remove security dialogs and restrictions. Replace the text of that file (in memory only) with your html text (`ie.document.body.innerhtml = Inp.readall`). Then read it back and write it out as text (`Outp.write ie.document.body.innertext`).

InP and OutP ane not defined in above code snippit but they are text stream objects.